# Is there a way I can initialize dictionary values to 0 in python taking keys from a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list to be used as keys for the dictionary and every value corresponding to the keys is to be initialized to 0.

Comment: `{k: 0 for k in key_list}`

Comment: Specifically for your case `dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], 0)` would result in `{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do with `dict.fromkeys`

```
In [34]: dict.fromkeys(range(5),0)
Out[34]: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
In [35]: dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'],0)
Out[35]: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
```

Comment: This helps. However what about a list of words as keys?

Comment: @NaveedUnjum It will work for the list of words too. Basically it will work for all kind of iterator.